# XAMPP OS X MariaDB datadir changed: mysql does not start

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp, mariadb

I downloaded XAMPP for OS X 5.6.14 for OS X that includes MariaDB.
Now I want to change the datadir from the database but that does not work. If I start mysql the lights from XAMPP controls are red but the service "mysql" is running...

my.cnf looks like this:

```
[client]
socket      = /Users/tobias/Documents/Webserver/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
socket      = /Users/tobias/Documents/Webserver/mysql/mysql.sock
datadir     = /Users/tobias/Documents/Webserver/mysql/
innodb_data_home_dir = /Users/tobias/Documents/Webserver/mysql/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /Users/tobias/Documents/Webserver/mysql/
```

I copied all files from the old directory to the new one and tried to start mysql.
After that, I got this error messages:

```
2015-12-05 19:50:18 140735225118720 [ERROR] Missing system table mysql.roles_mapping; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
2015-12-05 19:50:18 140735225118720 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH'), found type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_A
2015-12-05 19:50:18 140735225118720 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
```

Then I run mysql_upgrade and the errors were gone.
I've got no error in log but database does not start... service is running, but lights in Manager are red. phpmyadmin can not connect to db

Does anybody has an tutorial how I can move mysql database directory to a new one?

Permissions of the new folder is set to mysql:mysql

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `mysql_upgrade`?

Comment: Yes, I run mysql_upgrade. There were some more Configurations in XAMPP neccessary as only my.cnf. Solved it already and it is working great

Comment: If you solved it, please provide the answer for the benefit of this forum's readers.